# ( Flutter )How to call setState method of another class?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to call the method from another class , i used this approach but method is not calling properly .
`

````
        class PostModel extends StatefulWidget {
          final profilename;
          final bool isVideoUrl;
          final int urlsource;
          final videoUrl;
          const PostModel(
              {this.profilename,
              required this.isVideoUrl,
              required this.urlsource,
              this.videoUrl});
        
          @override
          State<PostModel> createState() => _PostModelState();
        }
        
        class _PostModelState extends State<PostModel> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                NameSection(),
                InkWell(
                  onDoubleTap: , // **toggleLike()** Want to call from here 
                  child: (widget.isVideoUrl)
                      ? SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: VideoController(videosUrl[widget.urlsource % 6]))
                      : Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              "https://picsum.photos/seed/${widget.urlsource}/400/400"),
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                ),
                PostIcons(), // here is the widget .
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child:
                        Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "11,536 likes",
                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "akashbanerjee ‍♀️",
                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "View all 244 comments ",
                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 186, 186, 186), fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "5 hours ago",
                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 186, 186, 186), fontSize: 10),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 77, 77),
                        indent: 0,
                        endIndent: 0,
                      )
                    ]))
              ],
            );
          }
        }
    
    ```
    ```
    
        class PostIcons extends StatefulWidget {
          const PostIcons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          State<PostIcons> createState() => PostIconsState();
        }
    
        class PostIconsState extends State<PostIcons> {
          bool liked = false;
        
          toggleLike() { // i want to call this function from above class.
            setState(() {
              liked = !liked;
            });
          }
        
          bool saved = false;
          toggleSavePost() {
            setState(() {
              saved = !saved;
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: (saved) ? Text("Post saved") : Text("Post unsaved"),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              ));
            });
          }
        
          showShareBottomModal() {
            // setState(() {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                // context and builder are
                // required properties in this widget
                backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 38, 38, 38),
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24), topRight: Radius.circular(24)),
                ),
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  // we set up a container inside which
                  // we create center column and display text
                  // Returning SizedBox instead of a Container
                  return SharePost();
                });
            // });
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: toggleLike,
                        iconSize: 28,
                        icon: Icon(
                          liked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_outline,
                          color: liked ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                        )),
                    // SizedBox(
                    //   width: 0,
                    // ),
                    Transform(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
                      child: IconButton(
                          iconSize: 28,
                          onPressed: null,
                          icon: Icon(
                            FeatherIcons.messageCircle,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: showShareBottomModal,
                        iconSize: 28,
                        icon: Icon(
                          FeatherIcons.send,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: toggleSavePost,
                  iconSize: 28,
                  icon: Icon(saved ? Icons.bookmark : Icons.bookmark_border_outlined),
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        }
````

> PostModel class

```
class Feeds extends StatefulWidget {
 

  @override
  State<Feeds> createState() => _FeedsState();
}

class _FeedsState extends State<Feeds> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(storyList.length, (index) {
        return PostModel(isVideoUrl: false, urlsource: index);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Postmodel widget  is inside List in another class.

so can anyone suggest me some good practical method of calling setState of other class (not a child , or parent  , full different class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `GlobalKey` like that you also need to give that key to the widget that you are trying to control with it. So in your case like

```
PostIcons(key: globalKey)
```

Here's a minimum working example of a widget controlling another widget using such key:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
final GlobalKey<AState> globalKey = GlobalKey();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(children: [
      A(key: globalKey),
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            globalKey.currentState?.increaseI();
          },
          child: Text("click"))
    ]))));
  }
}

class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<A> createState() => AState();
}

class AState extends State<A> {
  int i = 1;

  void increaseI() {
    setState(() {
      i++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(i.toString());
  }
}
```

EDIT:

So for your code, try to add

```
final GlobalKey<PostIconsState> globalKey = GlobalKey();
```

inside your `_PostModelState`. so right under

```
    class _PostModelState extends State<PostModel> {
```

Then this line:

```
            PostIcons(), // here is the widget .
```

you change to

```
            PostIcons(key: globalKey), // here is the widget .
```

then you can change

```
              onDoubleTap: , // **toggleLike()** Want to call from here
```

to

```
              onDoubleTap: () => globalKey.currentState?.toggleLike(),
```

I think the problem you had before was that the globalKey was defined outside the class. By defining it inside the class you make sure every instance has a different key

Comment: i changed the code like your answer but i am getting error i.e. "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey." , what should i do now.

Comment: @AdnanQureshi you should only be giving on widget that key. The error must mean you gave it to multiple

Comment: i am using that widget in a listview .

Comment: @AdnanQureshi it's hard to judge without seeing the full code. But if you have a list of these `PostIcons` then using a `GlobalKey` is probably not possible. As far as I understand it `GlobalKey` is only for when you have a single one. Or you need to maintain a list of `GlobalKey`s as well

Comment: so , what should be my approach to call toggleLike() function from PostModelState class mention in question.

Comment: @AdnanQureshi I can't answer that without seeing more code. It's impossible to tell. I don't know how `PostModel` and `PostIcons` are related.  You say there are not child and parent, but what are they then?

Comment: i added full code  to question.

Comment: @AdnanQureshi okay, I will take a look, give me some time